# How to converge on a value for an iterative function

Tags: python

`A iterative function I wrote is unable to converge on a value, I believe the function is not updating the last calculated value at the beginning of each new loop and thus not converging and instead calculating only one value each time.

Ive tried the function below, the issue is that for any f input I put it will calculate a subsequent f0 value but it wont repeat the loop with the new value and instead just return f0.`

```
import numpy as np

Q = 62549.5 #gpm
L = 52800 #ft
a = (100 / 1.10) #Right side of energy balance 
Vis = 1.537*10**(-5)
e = 0.0015 # in

f = 0.008
ep = 0.00001
list = np.linspace(0.005, 1, 5)


def friction(f):
  convergence = True
  while convergence:
    D = ((f*L*(Q**2))/(32.15*a))**(1/5)
    A = (3.14*(D/12)**2)/4 #ft^2
    v = (Q/448.831)/A #ft/s
    Re = (v*(D/12))/Vis
    f0 = 0.25/(np.log10(e/(3.7*D) + 5.74/(Re**(9/10))))**2

    convergence = abs((f0-f)/f0) < ep
    f = f0
    break
  return f0

for f in list:
   print(friction(f))
```

Comment: Did you mean to set `f = f0` before checking the difference between them?

Comment: I did not but the issue remains if I do move before the convergence check no matter the number I put it won't converge. I created a list of f values not shown above and iterated through them and they all returned unique "converged" f values.

Comment: Try adding some print statements to see what’s going wrong.  Either your ep is too big or you have a logic error.  Does “convergence = True” mean you have or haven’t converged?

Comment: Yes convergence = true should signify that it hasn't converged.

Comment: That seems backwards, but if that’s the case, shouldn’t it be False when the f-f0 difference is small?  Right now it’s the opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not 100% on whether the values It spit out for me are correct as I don't know much about calculating friction as i assume this is doing, this worked when I tried it(working meaning it gave different values when input was changed but same values for repeated inputs). you could try removing the break. I'm assuming that you may be breaking out of the loop before a convergence is met. you can add an if statement and set convergence to false when its met. or if you prefer to use break, you can use it instead in the if statement. Here's how I ran it, if I got the idea wrong I apologize.

```
import numpy as np

Q = 62549.5  # gpm
L = 52800  # ft
a = (100 / 1.10)  # Right side of energy balance
Vis = 1.537 * 10 ** (-5)
e = 0.0015  # in

f = 0.008
ep = 0.00001


def friction(f):
    convergence = True
    while convergence:
        D = ((f * L * (Q ** 2)) / (32.15 * a)) ** (1 / 5)
        A = (3.14 * (D / 12) ** 2) / 4  # ft^2
        v = (Q / 448.831) / A  # ft/s
        Re = (v * (D / 12)) / Vis
        f0 = 0.25 / (np.log10(e / (3.7 * D) + 5.74 / (Re ** (9 / 10)))) ** 2

        f = f0
        # I used an if statement so that when satisfied 
        # it sets convergence to false and loop ends
        if abs((f0 - f) / f0) < ep:
            convergence = False # This could be set to break, to
                                # immediately break loop if preferred
    return f0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    inPut = 0.008 # This is how I was changed input variable
    print(friction(inPut))
```

Comment: I appreciate the help it appears to converge around specific number ranges and when I compared it to my original function it does seem to converge across reasonable friction ranges. I really appreciate the help once again I've always struggled with these sorts of functions in python!